# How to get complete ms doc sharepoint url using Add-in

Tags: javascript, office365, office-js, office-addins, add-in

Suppose this the link of my word document-
https://-my.sharepoint.com/:w:/r/personal//_layouts/15/doc2.aspx?sourcedoc=%7B%7D&file=Document1.docx&action=...

while making a office word add-in and opening the word file in desktop or edge I want to retrieve complete url of word document.

On using Office.context.document.getFilePropertiesAsync or Office.context.document.url

I am able to get 'https://companyname-my.sharepoint.com/personal/username/Documents/Document 6.docx' but not the complete url.

Can anyone suggest a way using which I can get the complete url including email, sourcedocid .

Comment: This sounds like something you should resolve outside of the Add-In first, then implement in the Add-In. But I can't be sure of your goals.

Comment: I want to get complete URL of sharepoint including docID and user name which is present in url and I want to achieve the same using Word Add-in . That is the only goal. Using Office.context.document.getFilePropertiesAsync or Office.context.document.url. Which is provided in officeJS documentation is not giving me complete Url. Not only URL if you have any other solution to get the sourceDocId . You can tell me